# ¿Cómo hacer llamadas a una función desde un array en C++?

Tags: c++, array, funciones

Quiero almacenar varias llamadas a una función en un array, para así, utilizarla de forma repetida llamando a la posición concreta del array.

El problema es que en C++ hay que especificar el tipo de dato del array.

```
int llamadaFuncion [] = { 
      funcion(1, 10), 
      funcion(45, 50), 
      funcion(56, 43), 
      funcion(56, 10)};
}
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo, el tipo de dato no me importa, lo que necesito es poder llamar a una función en posiciones de un array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Creas un array de punteros a función
2. Usas `std::function`. Es un wrapper que encapsula los punteros a funciones

Un ejemplo con std::function

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void func1(int value)
{ std::cout << "func1 - " << value << '\n'; }

void func2(int value)
{ std::cout << "func2 - " << value << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int)> array[2] {
        func1,
        func2
    };

    for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (auto func : array)
        {
            func(i);        
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8Wo8nMprn03vCWB3)

El problema que tienes aquí (independientemente de la solución que uses) es que todas las funciones deben tener exactamente la misma interfaz, es decir, no te va a funcionar si una función no tiene parámetros, la otra recibe un `int`, otra un `float` y otra varios `string`

Si tu idea es que se llame a las funciones con unos parámetros por defecto, puedes usar lambdas:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void func1(int value)
{ std::cout << "func1 - " << value << '\n'; }

void func2(int value)
{ std::cout << "func2 - " << value << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    std::function<void(void)> array[] {
        []() { func1(1); },
        []() { func1(2); },
        []() { func2(3); },
        []() { func2(4); },
    };

    for (auto func : array)
    {
        func();        
    }
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K3MdDEP7Hv3XbYgh)

En este caso sí que podrás usar funciones de cualquier tipo, ya que al final lo que se invocan son las lambdas, las cuales sí que tendrás que garantizar que tienen todas la misma interfaz

Comment: Muchas gracias, respuesta muy completa.